# password reset swift 4 firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, swift4

Hey guys so I'm doing registration form with Swift 4 and using Firebase.

I'm stuck on reseting the password. Whenever I click on the button "forget password" I should get a pop up window with textField to fill in my email address. But when I do click nothing happens. Posting code below if anyone have some ideas what can be wrong with it

```
@IBAction func forgotPasswordTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let forgotPasswordAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Forgot password?", message: "Enter email address", preferredStyle: .alert)
    forgotPasswordAlert.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Enter email address"
    }
    forgotPasswordAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    forgotPasswordAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Reset Password", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        let resetEmail = forgotPasswordAlert.textFields?.first?.text
        Auth.auth().sendPasswordReset(withEmail: resetEmail!, completion: { (error) in
            if error != nil{
                let resetFailedAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Reset Failed", message: "Error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))", preferredStyle: .alert)
                resetFailedAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
                self.present(resetFailedAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }else {
                let resetEmailSentAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Reset email sent successfully", message: "Check your email", preferredStyle: .alert)
                resetEmailSentAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
                self.present(resetEmailSentAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        })
    }))
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a quick answer, you are simply forgetting to present your `forgotPasswordAlert`.  The fix is simple:

```
@IBAction func forgotPasswordTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let forgotPasswordAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Forgot password?", message: "Enter email address", preferredStyle: .alert)
    forgotPasswordAlert.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Enter email address"
    }
    forgotPasswordAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    forgotPasswordAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Reset Password", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        let resetEmail = forgotPasswordAlert.textFields?.first?.text
        Auth.auth().sendPasswordReset(withEmail: resetEmail!, completion: { (error) in
            if error != nil{
                let resetFailedAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Reset Failed", message: "Error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))", preferredStyle: .alert)
                resetFailedAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
                self.present(resetFailedAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }else {
                let resetEmailSentAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Reset email sent successfully", message: "Check your email", preferredStyle: .alert)
                resetEmailSentAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
                self.present(resetEmailSentAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        })
    }))
    //PRESENT ALERT
    self.present(forgotPasswordAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

As a small aside, you'll want to make sure you are presenting your confirmation alerts on the main queue to avoid unexpected behavior.  Perhaps the `sendPasswordReset` does this automatically, but I do not believe this to be the case.  Additionally, the better way of getting the error description to present to the user is with optional binding (using `if let`).

```
Auth.auth().sendPasswordReset(withEmail: resetEmail!, completion: { (error) in
    //Make sure you execute the following code on the main queue
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //Use "if let" to access the error, if it is non-nil
        if let error = error {
            let resetFailedAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Reset Failed", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            resetFailedAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(resetFailedAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            let resetEmailSentAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Reset email sent successfully", message: "Check your email", preferredStyle: .alert)
            resetEmailSentAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(resetEmailSentAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks ever so much! That was silly mistake made by me, just starting with swift hopefully going to get better haha

Answer (score 1):

**For swift 4.2**

```
import Firebase

// MARK: Firebase Forgotpassword
    func callFIRPasswordReset(){
        //show loader

        Auth.auth().sendPasswordReset(withEmail: self.txtEmail.text!) { (error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //hide loader

                self.txtEmail.text = ""

                if let error = error {
                    //show alert here
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
                else {
                    //show alert here
                    print("We send you an email with instructions on how to reset your password.")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```